# git lfs push is still attempting to upload many GB of non-lfs files

Tags: git, git-lfs

I think I understand the root cause of the issue I'm having but I don't know the best way to fix it. In the process of adding many .fbx files to my Unity game project, I did the following.

Before adding git lfs to my project:

1. I added the .fbx to my project
2. git add .
3. git commit -m "add fbx"
4. attempted a push to origin

Of course, this push failed, as the push in question was over 2 GB in size. I did some research on what I should do to address this, and found git lfs, which I have since installed, and created a proper .gitattributes which is properly marking all the large files. Using git lfs ls-files, I've confirmed that the large files in question are being handled by git lfs, and have been properly committed.

However, after all this setup, when I add, commit, and push, (and after a ~6GB LFS upload which seems to go off without a hitch) standard git is still attempting to upload a large amount of files (multiple GB in size, enough to get the push to fail). I assume this is happening because of my previous commit, before the files were marked as lfs.

How can I "reset" the situation here so that git stops attempting to upload a large amount of files without lfs?

I have tried checking out a new branch, adding, committing, and pushing, but the issue persists.

Comment: You need to rewrite your history. Drop or modify the commit(s) that has the large files by using `git rebase -i`.

Comment: See `git lfs import`. Note: Git is not aware that LFS exists. LFS has to "trick" Git into not storing the big files. That's why you're supposed to set up LFS first; if you start later, it's too late to *trick* Git, and that's when you need `import` to do the history rewrite.